# JQuery does not hide div if p element is before it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make use of a JQuery snippet to hide some content on SharePoint. It works without the `<p>` element, but SharePoint has a lot of stuff in between the `div` so I think that's why it's not working.

JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".ms-wpcontentdivspace").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
jQuery(".ms-webpart-chrome-title").click(function(e)
 {
   e.preventDefault();
   jQuery(this).next("div.ms-wpcontentdivspace").slideToggle(200);
 });
});
```

Here's the working code:

```
<div class="ms-webpart-chrome-title"><h2><a href="http://google.com"><span>Hello</span>      </a></h2></div>
<div class="ms-wpcontentdivspace">Hi there. I am hidden</div>
<div class="ms-webpart-chrome-title"><h2>Another title</h2></div>
<div class="ms-wpcontentdivspace">More hidden stuff</div>
```

Here's the code that doesn't:

```
<div class="ms-webpart-chrome-title"><h2><a href="http://google.com"><span>Hello</span></a></h2></div>
<p>some text</p>
<div class="ms-wpcontentdivspace">Hi there. I am hidden</div>
<div class="ms-webpart-chrome-title"><h2>Another title</h2></div>
<div class="ms-wpcontentdivspace">More hidden stuff</div>
```

[Here's a Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QkrxQ/). Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what the question/problem is.

Comment: jQuery doesn't care what the element is. `hide()` simply sets its style to `display: none`, the rest is up to the browser.

Comment: The problem is your use of `.next()`. When there's a `<p>` in between, the hidden element isn't the next element any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery version used 1.3.x is pretty old, anyway try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".ms-wpcontentdivspace").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    jQuery(".ms-webpart-chrome-title").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).nextAll("div.ms-wpcontentdivspace").eq(0).slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Fsgf4/)

Comment: You answered first so instead of posting another answer, ill just add it here : `nextAll("div.ms-wpcontentdivspace:first")` work too.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it doesn't seem to work on the SharePoint site (of course). I really hate this POS. Here's a screenshot of the code...somehow the div is not even hidden on page load.

[screenshot](http://imgur.com/j1UpcXR)

Comment: @Steve Classes are case-sensitive. `ms-wpContentDivSpace` != `ms-wpcontentdivspace`.

Comment: @Steve also the structure is very different from what you have shared... `ms-wpcontentdivspace` is not a sibling of `ms-webpart-chrome-title`

Comment: @Steve Try `Query(this).closest('.ms-webpart-chrome').find("div.ms-wpContentDivSpace").eq(0).slideToggle(200);`

Comment: @ArunPJohny That worked. Thanks so much! The example didn't seem to have the div be a sibling (the div containing the h2) was closed so I thought it was a similar situation. Thanks again for the help and patience...this isn't my official job title and yet I'm stuck doing development :(

Answer (score 0):

`$.next()` only gets the immediately following sibling, so you will want to use `$.nextAll()`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".ms-wpcontentdivspace").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
jQuery(".ms-webpart-chrome-title").click(function(e)
 {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   jQuery(this).nextAll("div.ms-wpcontentdivspace").eq(0).slideToggle(200);
 });
});
```